# How to assign a user id to a record in the backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make sure that when I create a record in the front end, the user id of the user who created it is automatically assigned to this record. What should I do in the backend if I want the id of the authorized user to be automatically assigned to the record when creating the record? For authorization I use gem 'devise_token_auth'.

notebooks_controller.rb:

```
class NotebooksController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_notebook, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]


    def index
      @notebooks = Notebook.all

      render json: @notebooks
    end

    def show
      render json: @notebook
    end

    def create
      @notebook = Notebook.new(notebooks_params)

      if @notebook.save
        render json: @notebook, status: :created, location: @notebook
      else
        render json: @notebook.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    def update
      if @notebook.update(notebooks_params)
        render json: @notebook
      else
        render json: @notebook.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @spr_contract_solution.destroy
    end

    private
      def set_notebook
        @notebook = Notebook.find(params[:id])
      end

    def notebooks_params
      params.require(:notebook).permit!
    end
end
```

notebook.rb:

```
class Notebook < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

...._create_notebooks.rb

```
class CreateNotebooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :notebooks do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.boolean :is_active
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: don't you need to pass the list of params in your `permit!` method ? and it should have the user id through your association

Comment: @Subash I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand what you mean, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, @Subash is right, you need to pass the list of parameters to the `permit` method  in `notebook_params` (note that maybe you would want to use `permit` instead of `permit!`), for example:

```
params.require(:notebook).permit :name, :text, :any_other_attribute_you_are_saving
```

Then, to answer your question, you could do something like this in the `create` action:

```
@notebook = Notebook.new(notebooks_params)
@notebook.user = current_user #Assuming you have this method available
```

Comment: This is a pretty straight-forward way of doing this, but you can also do `current_user.notebooks.build(notebooks_params)` if you want it pre-associated to the user and you have a `has_many` relationship in place.

Comment: No, you don't _need_ to pass keys to `permit!`. That's for `permit`. And `permit!` is the lazy "allow all".

Comment: You're right, I just copy/pasted from the question code. I'll edit my answer to use `permit`

Comment: @GabrielSánchez: thumbs up for the edit, but Subash didn't say that. While it's a good practice indeed (using `permit` and explicit whitelist), this is in no way required here.

Comment: Goes such a mistake although I do as you say `Processing by NotebooksController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"title"=>"dfsf", "description"=>"sdfsdf", "notebook"=>{"title"=>"dfsf", "description"=>"sdfsdf"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0)):

app/controllers/notebooks_controller.rb:44:in `notebooks_params'
app/controllers/notebooks_controller.rb:16:in create `

Comment: Seems like you're calling `notebook_params` with 4 arguments, you shouldn't.  
 `def notebooks_params
    params.require(:notebook).permit :title, :description
  end` 

And in the `create` action just put `@notebook = Notebook.new notebooks_params`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `has_many :notebooks` in your user model, this is a popular idiom for doing what you want:

```
@notebook = current_user.notebooks.build(notebook_params)
```

Comment: Note that `notebooks_params` should really be called `notebook_params`. There's only one notebook there.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
@notebook.user = current_user
```

after

```
@notebook = Notebook.new(notebooks_params)
```